# Build a data transformation service using Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Kafka Streams is good, but I have to do every configuration very manual. Instead Kafka Connect provides its API interface, which is very useful for handling the configuration, as well as Tasks, Workers, etc...

Thus, I'm thinking of using Kafka Connect for my simple data transforming service. Basically, the service will read the data from a topic and send the transformed data to another topic. In order to do that, I have to make a custom Sink Connector to send the transformed data to the kafka topic, however, it seems those interface functions aren't available in SinkConnector. If I can do it, that would be great since I can manage tasks, workers via the REST API and running the tasks under a distributed mode (multiple instances).

There are 2 options in my mind:

- Figuring out how to send the message from SinkConnector to a kafka topic
- Figuring out how to build a REST interface API like Kafka Connect which wraps up the Kafka Streams app

Any ideas?

Comment: Kafka connect was created to connect kafka brokers to external systems, not to do streaming. If you think that Kafka stream is not good you can connect kafka brokers to another stream engine (Spark, Flink, ...) Using kafka connect.

Answer (score 0):

> - Figuring out how to send the message from SinkConnector to a kafka topic

A sink connector consumes data/messages from a Kafka topic. If you want to send data to a Kafka topic you are likely talking about a source connector.

> - Figuring out how to build a REST interface API like Kafka Connect which wraps up the Kafka Streams app.

using the [kafka-connect-archtype](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-archtype) you can have a template to create your own Kafka connector (source or sink). In your case that you want to build some stream processing pipeline after the connector, you are mostly talking about a connector of another stream processing engine that is not Kafka-stream. There are connectors for Kafka <-> Spark, Kafka <-> Flink, ...

But you can build your using the template of [kafka-connect-archtype](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-archtype) if you want. Use the [MySourceTask](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-archtype/blob/master/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java/MySourceTask.java) `List<SourceRecord> poll()` method or the [MySinkTask](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-archtype/blob/master/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java/MySinkTask.java) `put(Collection<SinkRecord> records)` method to process the records as stream. They extend the `org.apache.kafka.connect.[source.SourceTask|sink.SinkTask]` from Kafka connect.

Comment: thanks let me look into kafka-connect-archtype

Comment: I was implementing a github kafka source connector last week and it seems to be possible to use the `poll()` method. In this example I collect a fixed size list and only few items of the `SourceRecord` (https://github.com/felipegutierrez/kafka-connector-github-source/blob/main/src/main/java/com/github/felipegutierrez/kafka/connector/github/GitHubSourceTask.java#L131). In your case you will use the `SinkRecord`.

Answer (score 0):

> a REST interface API like Kafka Connect which wraps up the Kafka Streams app

This is *exactly* what KsqlDB allows you to do

Outside of creating streams and tables with SQL queries, it offers a REST API as well as can interact with Connect endpoints (or embed a Connect worker itself)

https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/concepts/connectors/